# Solr Deployment on Websphere 8.5.5 as WAR application

Tags: java, solr, websphere-8

I am installing solr on WAS 8.5.5 with IBM jdk 7.
I deployed the `solr` as a `war` and added `solr.data.dir` and `solr.solr.home` to custom properties.

[image]

Upon accessing the url: `http://localhost:9080/solr`,

I see the below error on the browser:

> Error 500: javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter [SolrRequestFilter]: org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter was found, but is missing another required class

And the following error in  the logs:

> SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor]: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter (initialization failure) at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:176) at java.lang.J9VMInternals.newInstanceImpl(Native Method) at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1600) at java.beans.Beans.instantiate(Beans.java:241) at java.beans.Beans.instantiate(Beans.java:89) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager._loadFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:533) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.loadFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:475) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.getFilterInstanceWrapper(WebAppFilterManager.java:308) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.getFilterChain(WebAppFilterManager.java:380) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:892) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025).....

The lib folder of WEB-INF do contain  the solr dependencies 
[image]

Any Help from anybody ?

Comment: Only thing I can think of is you're missing some of the logging jars. You need all the jars that can be found in lib/ext.

Comment: To the solr.war/WEB-INF/lib, I have added all the jars from solr/dist + solr/dist/solrj-lib + solr/examples/lib/ext. These extra jars are added on the top of all the jars which are aleady present in the solr.war/WEB-INF/lib. I have also changed the class loading to "PARENT_LAST"

Answer (score 1):

After scratching  my head for 48 hours, finally able to make SOLR up and running on WebSphere. 
Looks like the whole fundamental is to understand the class loading strategy on WAS8, and hence choosing the right strategy.

Have enumerated the different steps for solr deployment on WAS 8

[Solr Deployment on WebSphere 8.5.5](http://was8.blogspot.in/2015/03/solr-4102-deployment-on-websphere-855.html)